# What is the equivalent in nodeJS of the expression below?

Tags: c#, node.js, encoding, utf-8, cryptography

Can someone help me to get this done in NodeJs

Below is an example (C#) with brief description on how to compute signature: I want it in Node JS

1. Encode the lower case of integrator key to bytes in UTF-8 format var `keyToBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(integratorKey.ToString().ToLower());`
2. Create a HMACSHA256 routine that uses the key bytes as the encryption key var `hmacSha256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(keyToBytes);`
3. Create the signature by encrypting the encoded endpoint (Absolute path of the URI only) and timestamp `var signatureBytes = utf8.GetBytes(String.Concat(new Uri(url).AbsolutePath, timeStamp));`
4. Convert the encrypted string to base-64 string format `var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(signatureBytes));`

Comment: It makes more sense to post the reference code in an executable format (with regard to reproducibility by copy/paste). Post also your most recent NodeJS code.

Comment: @Topaco you're right. I was supposed to do the same but unfortunately I don't have any working snippet in c# either and also i don't understand the encoding terms its so confusing for me. I've been trying for more than 3 hours but didn't succeed. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const url = require('url');

const urlExample = 'http://localhost/test/resource';
const integratorKeyString = 'dDASDaGdj5R1kf5151ladAFvv';
const keyToBytes = Buffer.from(integratorKeyString.toLowerCase());
const hmacSha256 = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', keyToBytes);
const signatureBytes = Buffer.from(url.parse(urlExample).pathname + Date.now());
const signature = hmacSha256.update(signatureBytes).digest('base64');

console.log(signature);
```

Comment: thanks! it worked. I really appreciate your input.

Comment: I am very glad that my decision helped you. Regarding thanks in the comments - you need to read this help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Thanks you.